# flask installation error in running _init_.py

Tags: python-3.6

I have this error while installing Flask in command prompt:

> ```
> (flask) C:\myproject\app>python_init_.py
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "_init_.py", line 3, in <module>
>         app = Flask<_name_>
> NameError: name '_name_' is not defined
> ```

What does this mean, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The dunder name variable is `__name__` with two underscores (for **init**.py by the way) on both side. Also your should have parenthesis not `<>`:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
```

You can read more about dunder variable and methods in [the official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html).

*Sidenote: 
A common convention in python is to name your main package by the name of your project in lowercase. From that I tend to use `__package__` instead of `__name__`. Flask example are simple enough to work in a one file structure but in real world you probably gonna have more. Therefore `__name__` will be `__init__` from the module name while `__package__` will be equal to project/app name*